# What is the difference between "npm update -g", "npm upgrade -g", "npm install -g npm", and "n stable"?

Tags: node.js, npm

My npm seems out of date, so it seems I could use four different ways to update it:

```
sudo npm update -g          # => npm 3.8.6
sudo npm upgrade -g         # => npm 3.8.7
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm cache clean -f && sudo npm install -g n && sudo n stable
```

Some of the methods above installed npm 3.8.6, some installed 3.8.7, and the last one by `n` installed 3.8.3.

What are the differences between these methods and is there a standard way / official way to do it?

(The 3.8.6 and 3.8.7 difference was on my MacBook 12 inch Retina with [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan). It wasn't so on my MacBook Pro with [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks).)

Answer (score 39):

What those commands do:

1. `sudo npm update -g` - this command updates all installed global packages to the the latest versions.
2. `sudo npm upgrade -g` - it's an alias for `update` command.
3. `sudo npm install -g npm` - installs the latest available version of npm package.
4. `sudo npm cache clean -f && sudo npm install -g n && sudo n stable` - cleans the npm cache, installs `n` (node version manager) and the latest available node.js and npm.

So, if you need update `npm` to the latest version only, use `sudo npm install -g npm`, if you want to update and node and npm, use `sudo npm cache clean -f && sudo npm install -g n && sudo n stable`.

Comment: `update` gave npm 3.8.6 while `upgrade` gave npm 3.8.7 on my Macbook 12 inch with El Capitan... not on the Macbook Pro with Mavericks -- they both gave npm 3.8.6 on Mavericks

Comment: Run `npm update -h` and `npm updrade -h` and you will see that upgrade is an alias for update.

Comment: Just remember if you're not logged in as root, it will preform all of those commands under the root user and not your account. If you can avoid it, don't use the root account, and install npm under your other account. This helps you create npmrc files for different purposes/reasons. For users of ubuntu, you're most likely not logged in as root and shouldn't use sudo. Also, I don't believe it's necessary to add sudo to chained commands. The first sudo will follow execution until the chain is done.