# Firebase Cloud Functions "admin.messaging(...).send is not a function"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a function in Firebase Functions service that send any FCM.
I would to use admin.messaging().send() function, like [this reference guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#send), but I got this error while function is triggered, not during deploy:

```
TypeError: admin.messaging(...).send is not a function
   at exports.sendChatNotification.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/user_code/lib/index.js:113:30)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
   at next (native)
   at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
   at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
   at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
   at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I can see this error in Functions->Log inside Firebase console.
That's my function code:

```
 exports.sendChatNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages').onCreate(event => {

 var message = {
    data: {
        title: 'title',
        body: 'body',
    },
    apns: {
        header: {
            'apns-priority': '10',
            'apns-expiration':'0'
          },
        payload: {
            aps: {
                sound: 'default',
                'content-available':'1'
              }
        }
    },
    android: {
        ttl: 60*1000,
        priority: 'high'
      },
    topic: 'mytopic'
};

return admin.messaging().send(message);

});
```

If I use admin.messaging().sendToTopic() and (changing the message structure) it works fine. It seems Firebase doesn't support its own API.

I deploy this using Firebase tools, with command line "firebase deploy".
I have updated firebase-tools and firebase-functions and firebase-admin in my functions project.

Comment: Your error message shows a problem with "sendChatNotitifcation", but you're showing code for "sendMessage".  Please make sure you have all the correct information here.  Also please indicate which version of firebase-admin you're using.

Comment: I correct the question, I had typed by hand the first line.....there is same function.

Comment: Also please indicate which version of firebase-admin you're using,

Comment: I update it before this question...."firebase-admin": "~5.4.2" (from package.json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Messaging in Cloud Functions: admin.messagin(...).send is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894575/cloud-messaging-in-cloud-functions-admin-messagin-send-is-not-a-function)

Comment: please check the `Note` in the duplicate

Comment: I updated using "npm update -g firebase-admin" in functions folder, but my version remain 5.4.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The send() function was added in firebase-admin 5.9.0.  If you want to use it, you should run `npm install firebase-admin@latest` in your functions folder to install the latest version.  At the time of this writing, the latest version is 5.9.1.

Comment: I have this error now, when deploy: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'node-forge'

Comment: I have installed it calling (in function folder): npm install node-forge

Comment: Maybe you just need to `npm install` to get everything from your package.json installed.

Comment: @DougStevenson why didnt `npm update -g firebase-admin` not work? Shouldnt it work according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668498/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-update-g-npm-upgrade-g-npm-install?

Comment: @PeterHaddad That's not related.  Running that command with -g tells npm to install the firebase-admin package globally, so that you can use `firebase` on the command line.  Running without -g tells npm to update the current project folder only, which only affects the code you deploy.  Globally installed modules are not part of a Firebase project deployment.

Comment: @DougStevenson ohh okay thank you for explaining it to me, I will fix it in the other answer then to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DougStevenson I run npm install firebase-admin@latest from cli. It looks latest version now but I am getting same error.. Do you suggest something ?

Comment: I have the same problem: running this command does not fix the error.